# Probability that two samples from the same population are contained within each other or share an element

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations, statistical-inference, order-statistics

I'm not sure if this is a tractable question or not. And I am unsure where to start. 
I've attempted the chained combinations formula. but at even these sample sizes excel breaks. So I'm not sure my approach is correct.

- Population size: 1000 units
- Sample 1 size: 300 units
- Sample 2 size: 450 units

Order does not matter. Each sample is taken independently but from the same population.

Assuming normal distribution, is it possible to determine:

1. A. Probability that At least 1 unit from sample 1 is contained in sample 2?
2. B. Probability that Sample 1 is entirely contained in sample 2?

Comment: Are the 300 units drawn with replacement (i.e. allowing repeats of the same unit) or without replacement (no repeats)?

Comment: Yes drawn with replacement. (Elements of sample 1 can be in Sample 2)

Comment: no, I mean within sample $1$ itself, can the $300$ draws map to only e.g. $293$ individuals because some of them gets picked multiple times within sample $1$?

Comment: Ah. In that case the 300 are selected without replacement. same for all other samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So each sample is drawn without replacements (i.e. no repeats within each sample), but of course after sample $1$ everything is replaced before drawing sample $2$.

The number of ways to draw both samples is ${1000 \choose 300} \times {1000 \choose 450}$

**Part A:** Drawing both samples in a way they don't overlap, means the second sample must come from the remaining $700$ not in the first sample.  The number of ways is ${1000 \choose 300} \times {700 \choose 450}$

These calculations might break excel, but they don't break e.g. [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7B1000+%5Cchoose+300%7D+%7B700+%5Cchoose+450%7D%29+%2F+%28%7B1000+%5Cchoose+300%7D+%7B1000+%5Cchoose+450%7D%29) which says:

$$P(\text{no overlap}) = {{1000 \choose 300} \times {700 \choose 450} \over {1000 \choose 300} \times {1000 \choose 450}} \approx 2.4 \times 10^{-101}$$

$$P(\text{at least one overlap}) = 1 - P(\text{no overlap}) \approx 1 - 2.4 \times 10^{-101} \approx 1$$

**Part B:** Drawing both samples in a way that sample $1$ is a subset of sample $2$, means sample $2$ only needs to draw the $450-300 = 150$ extra units from the $700$ not in sample $1$.  The number of ways is ${1000 \choose 300} \times {700 \choose 150}$ and again [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7B1000+%5Cchoose+300%7D+%7B700+%5Cchoose+150%7D%29+%2F+%28%7B1000+%5Cchoose+300%7D+%7B1000+%5Cchoose+450%7D%29) says:

$$P(\text{sample $1 \subset$ sample $2$}) = {{1000 \choose 300} \times {700 \choose 150} \over {1000 \choose 300} \times {1000 \choose 450}} \approx 1.8 \times 10^{-141} \approx 0$$

Hope this answers your question...?